# How to renew TLS certs in hyperledger fabric after they have expired?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

My orderers and peers aren't able to communicate . They are giving bad certificate errorr. I don't want to loose any data .

```
2020-12-18 12:47:46.820 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 990 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.29.0.7:58636
```

Comment: Are you using Kafka or Raft consensus?

Comment: I'm using Raft and hyperledger fabric 1.4 version

Comment: @GariSingh my all orderer nodes are giving Bad certificate so i think i have to do certificate rotation for orderers too ? 
I've posted another separate question for certificate rotation of orderers too .

Comment: I do post how to handle orderers below as well.  The main "trick" to make life easy is to use the same private key for each orderer and simply renews the public certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ***peers***, it's very straightforward:

- issue new TLS certificates from the same CA which issued their current certs
- replace the existing certificates (or update `core.yaml` to point to the new certificates if using different paths/filenames)
- restart the peer(s)

For ***orderers*** using Raft, it's a bit trickier.  Assuming you are on the latest 1.4.x version, what you need to do for orderers is use their existing private keys to generate new CSRs and then have the CA issue a new public certificate.  You will then replace / update `orderer.yaml` the public certificate and restart the orderers one at a time.

Comment: I tried doing it but when i restart the orderer it never achieves consensus back.